# How to implement page curl with the new iOS 5 Newsstand sdk in Monotouch?

Tags: ios, pdf, xamarin.ios, page-curl

Apple finally released the api for their PageCurl transition effect in iOS 5.0 SDK:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

I want to do a transition between the pages of a PDF in my Newsstand App, but I don't know how to do it in MonoTouch. I downloaded the [Newsstand.zip](http://docs.xamarin.com/@api/deki/files/322/=Newsstand.zip) example as told on the Xamarin website:

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Introduction_to_iOS_5#Newsstand

But it doesn't show how to display a PDF using the new PageCurl effect. :(

How can I use the Page Curl transition in MonoTouch?

Any help, no matter how small, is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a simple example on my [blog](http://software.tavlikos.com/2011/10/13/uipageviewcontroller/). It does not include using it for PDF files, it is merely a simple usage of the UIPageViewController class. It might help you though.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! Your project should be on GitHub! But how I can use it to turn the pages of a PDFs? Do I need to just add a CGPDFDocument to the View?

Comment: You are welcome, glad I help. I didn't have time to do tests with various types of content, but I suppose it will work with whatever you include in your "pages".

Comment: I've managed to make a simple test project with a PDF, but somehow it crashes every time. Check it on GitHub: https://github.com/Emasoft/IpaziaPDFReader